# reversing a section of string in python with [start:stop:step]

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am learning python and I can't solve this problem:
I am ok to reverse the whole string but I want to get only the "Hello" part

```
astring = "Hello world!"
```

I was expecting `print(astring[0:4:-1])` would do the work but it does not.
`print(astring[5:0:-1])` is better but the H is still missing. I get `"olle"`

Is there anyway to solve this?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print(astring[4::-1])
```